# Verify HASH value of certificate

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

How can I verify Hash value of a certificate I get from a website using openssl? Say for example  or [facebook.com](https://facebook.com).

Comment: Typically with the `s_client` OpenSSL sub command. That has its own manual page with further options and examples.

Comment: Downvoting for not showing any effort.

Comment: Thank you, no problem, I am completely new to subject matter and this was a question to me, so I really couldn't find a clue on doing it in short time. Any way thank you for giving time to look at the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it if I remember correctly. You did ask for the hash and not the modulus.

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -hash
```

Comment: Be aware that the output will change between openssl 0.9.8 and 1.0.0, as SHA1 one is used to calculate the hash in newer versions compared to MD5 in 0.9.8. Use `-subject_hash_old` for the MD5 hash in the new versions if you need to compare against output from and older version